# tf.py_function not able to return a list?

Tags: python, tensorflow

consider

```
>>> f = lambda x:[x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4]
>>> tf.py_function([1],[tf.int32])
    [<tf.Tensor: id=7370, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>]
```

However, when I do this

```
>>> f = lambda x,y:([x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4,x+5],[x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4,x+5])
>>> tf.py_function(f,[1,1],[tf.int32,tf.int64])
    [<tf.Tensor: id=7509, shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])>,
     <tf.Tensor: id=7510, shape=(5,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int64)>]
```

I've found this to be weird. At first example, I thought it doesn't return a list but only return its first value because my return type `Tout=tf.int32`. So it assumes it only returns a integer not list.

However, at my second example, where `Tout=[tf.int32,tf.int64]` it returns two list; first list `tf.int32` and second list `tf.int64` indicates that `tf.int32` doesn't imply just return integer value; it still can represent a list of integers.

Anyone knows how to properly fix it so it returns valid list of values?

Answer (score 4):

It is actually pretty simple as below,

**Fixed Code -**

```
f = lambda x:[[x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4]]
tf.py_function(f,[1],[tf.int32])
```

**Output -**

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)>]
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @ElleryL - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.